# MySQL: is commenting out `bind-address: 127.0.0.1` same as setting `bind-address: 0.0.0.0`?

Tags: mysql

in `my.cnf` file I have the following line which binds to localhost:

```sql
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

My question is: Is commenting out `bind-address` the same thing as `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`?

```sql
# bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

same thing?

```sql
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: `show variables like 'bind_address'`

Comment: That `SHOW` will tell you what value was stored, hence giving you the answer.

Comment: thanks @RickJames